# rake assets:precompile heroku doesn't pick up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

Ahh, I am gettting headaches from this assets:precompile thing. When I first pushed app to heroku, I precomipled them locally. This was all good, but then it wouldn't pick up any changes to css files I made after that in development, because it served the precompiled assets. So now, for the visual things, I had to do rake assets:clean. I made the changes I wanted to app locally, without problems. Then, I precompiled assets again, and pushed the changes to heroku, but now it seems as it won't even see my assets.The page is just white with stuff on it, without any styling whatsoever.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having problems with 2 parts of the heroku system:

---

[**Asset Fingerprinting**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

Asset fingerprinting basically adds an MD5 hash to the end of your asset files, to keep them unique & dependent of any relations they have in the file. It's important because each time you compile your assets, they generate these new filenames which will cause standard CSS to mess up

You need to do this with all of your asset references in your CSS:

> **Change your CSS files to .css.scss**

Unlike static CSS, SCSS is compiled dynamically, and can parse ruby code. This means you can reference your assets like this:

```
background-url: asset_url('/nav_bar/nagivgation_bg.png');
```

Do this for your CSS files and the references should be okay

---

**[Serve Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)**

Heroku needs you to run static assets in Rails. This is very simple to do:

```
#/config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

---

**Update**

Here is some live code to demonstrate where to include dynamic helpers in the .scss file:

```
.confirmation .action_bar a.confirm {
        color: #fff;
        background: asset_url('modals/confirm_button/bg.png') top repeat-x;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 0 0 7px;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, since I am a little new to the whole assets on heroku thing. My css files are already .css.scss. Where should I put this code: background-url: asset_path('/nav_bar/nagivgation_bg.png');

Comment: No problem - I just put up a vanilla answer because I didn't know how much experience you have :) The asset_path stuff is an example of how you can use the dynamic paths in .scss -> it should actually be "asset_url", and basically replace ANY url() you have (as they will just reference static files). I've updated my answer with a live example

Comment: I don't think I have any urls in the scss files.